# Random white line showing up between views when using Form

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-form

I've been messing with this for quite some time now and cannot for the life of me figure out where this little white line is coming from. I tried setting `.padding(0)` and using a `.frame()` but nothing seems to work to remove it. If I remove the Form and use something like just a `list`, it goes away but I like the Inset look of `Form`. If I add the style for the inset look on the list, the issue comes back.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(settings.accentColor)
            .overlay(
                Group {
                    Text("x").font(.system(size: 50, weight: .heavy))
                    Text("xxxxxxxxx").font(.system(size: 36, weight: .regular))
                    
                }.foregroundColor(.white)
            )
        
        Form {
            TextField("Test", text: $test)
        }
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `spacing` parameter to your `VStack`

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeScotto yeah, default values can be surprising=)